# Google WebApp on mobile device not adjusting to smaller screen

Tags: html, google-apps-script, mobile, screen, viewport

I made a very simple webapp in Google App Script as an example.  I want to render the html by a template from a file because I want to use partials for my javascript and css.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main").evaluate();
}
```

Although I use the meta tag with viewport, I can't render my site decently on a mobile device.  It shows on a smartphone as if it was on a laptopscreen.  The problems stays when I use in the "doGet()" the method "HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("main")" .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
      input { width:100% }
    </style>


  </head>
  <body>

     <h1>Hello</h1>

     <label>Your name: </label>
     <input></input> 


  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: 100% width is a bit much and you may need to adjust sizes depending upon different screen widths with media queries

Comment: See my answer in the linked duplicate. Your script is not using the proper way to include Meta tags.